# Why do I find it tough dealing with web.config?

Tags: wcf

Is it only me or all of you find it difficult editing web.config for WCF? There are so many attributes and so many "magic" values that you need to remember. How to overcome this problem? Is there any tool available for editing WCF config file or do I have to stuff all these junk XML in my mind? I must confess even if I practice 10 times I find all the XML fairly new when i see it after a month. Configuring the IMexDataExchange and security and sessions and transactions in WCF completely leaves me clueless

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at the WCF Service Configuration Editor. Your should be able to find it here: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0\Bin\SvcConfigEditor.exe

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732009.aspx

Comment: Thanks Flo, but still exporting metadata of service using IMexDataExchange and such weird classes has to typed by hand i guess. The tool doesn't support this.

Comment: @Ankit: what do you mean? I configure MEX through the editor all the time.

Comment: Ya ok i found the option just now. Thanks John